# comprimir zip con java

Tags: java, pdf, jsf, primefaces, zip

he generado mi codigo mi codigo para crear un zip apartir de una variable que tiene el contenido a comprimir en este caso son pdf , el problema es que se realiza la descarga del zip pero este viene con pdf de dañado y con 0 de tamaño.
les comparto parte de mi codigo donde hace la compresion.

tengo un ouputstream que es ahi donde se guardan los pdfs que necesito comprimir y es el que paso al metodo zip para realizar la compresion.

```
public void generarPDF(Long idEnvio ) {
        try {
            String nombre = "envio-taller" + idEnvio + ".pdf";
            List<ByteArrayOutputStream> outputStreams = 
            this.enviosLocalesServicio.crearReportes(idEnvio);

            zip(outputStreams);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
    }

private byte[] zip(List<ByteArrayOutputStream> outputStreams ) throws 
        ServletException, IOException  {
        ByteArrayOutputStream zip = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ZipOutputStream zout = null;
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) 
        facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
        try {
            int zipNombre = 0;
            zout = new  ZipOutputStream(zip);
            for (ByteArrayOutputStream doc : outputStreams) {   
                zipNombre ++ ;
                ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(zipNombre + ".pdf");
                zout.putNextEntry(ze);
                zout.write(doc.toByteArray());              
                zout.closeEntry(); 
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.info(e.getMessage());
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            log.info(e.getMessage());
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (zout != null) {         
                ServletOutputStream resp = response.getOutputStream() ;
//              response.reset();
                response.setContentType("application/zip");
                response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=documen.ZIP" );

                resp.write(zip.toByteArray());
                resp.close();
                facesContext.responseComplete();
                zout.close();
            }
        }
        return zip.toByteArray();
    }
```

Comment: Me da la sensación de que tu `outputstream` esta vacío. Eso quiere decir que el problema puede ser la función `crearReportes` pero no la pusiste

Comment: la funcion crea los reportes, esta generando el pdf con datos
primero probe con descargar el puro pdf y funciona ahora lo que quiero hacer es que esos pdf que se generan se descargen dentro de un zip

Comment: y el código????

Comment: ya esta el codigo

Answer (score 0):

esto es parte del codigo

```
public List<ByteArrayOutputStream> crearReportes(Long idEnvio) throws OutletExcepcion {
        List<ByteArrayOutputStream> pdfs = null;
        try {
            EnvioLocalDTO envioDatos = this.obtenerEnvio(idEnvio);
            if (envioDatos!= null) {
                pdfs = new ArrayList<ByteArrayOutputStream>();
                ByteArrayOutputStream pdf=null;
                Empresa empresa = empresaServicio.obtenerEmpresa(1);
                opcionesBucket bucket = opcionesBucket.configuracion_app;
                String url = storageServicio.consultaporNombre(bucket, null, empresa.getImagen3());

                Map<Integer, List<EnvioLocalDetDTO>> detallesTaller = envioDatos.getDetallesTaller();
                for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<EnvioLocalDetDTO>> entry : detallesTaller.entrySet()) {
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");              
                    Map<String, Object> datos = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    datos.put("fecha", sdf.format(envioDatos.getFecha()));
                    datos.put("chofer", envioDatos.getNombreChofer());
                    datos.put("folio", envioDatos.getIdEnvio());
                    datos.put("idRuta", envioDatos.getIdRuta());
                    datos.put("nombreRuta", envioDatos.getNombreRuta());
                    datos.put("nombreTaller", envioDatos.getActuales().get(0).getNombreTaller());
                    datos.put("nombreMarca", envioDatos.getActuales().get(0).getNombreMarca());
                    datos.put("nombreTipo", envioDatos.getActuales().get(0).getNombreTipo());
                    datos.put("modelo", envioDatos.getActuales().get(0).getModelo());

                    JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(entry.getValue());
                    pdf = UtileriaPdf.crearReporte(Constantes.PLANTILLAPDF_INVENTARIO_TALLER, datos, dataSource, empresa, url);
                    pdfs.add(pdf);
                }       
            } else throw new
```